# What does (v@(x:xs) mean in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

Whats the difference between:

```
(v@(x:xs)) and (v:(x:xs)
```

Example function:

```
list [] = []
list (v@(x:xs)) = v : list xs
```

If i replace the (v@(x:xs)) with (v:(x:xs)) the function doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v@(x:xs)` matches a list with **one** or more, with `x` bound to the head, `xs` to the tail, and `v` to the entire list.

`v:(x:xs)` matches a list with **two** or more elements, with `v` bound to the first, `x` to the second, and `xs` to the rest.